# how to fix [!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-loud-speaker'. No podspec file was found

Tags: react-native

help me to fix  this sir
[!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-loud-speaker'. No podspec file was found.

[!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-loud-speaker'. No podspec file was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing suggests that a required podspec file for the react-native-loud-speaker package was not found. This could happen if the package was not installed correctly or if there is an issue with your React Native project's configuration.

**Solution 1:**

To solve it you will need to reinstall the package

```
npm uninstall react-native-loud-speaker
npm install react-native-loud-speaker --save
cd ios
pod install
```

**Solution 2:**

I've checked the package and it's an old library and the file doesn't exist you can try to find another package or you can add it by yourself by creating a file named `react-native-loud-speaker.podspec` in the `ios` directory of your project. You can then add the following code to the file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "react-native-loud-speaker"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "A React Native module for controlling loud speaker mode on iOS devices."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/example/react-native-loud-speaker"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author       = { "Your Name" => "your_email@example.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/example/react-native-loud-speaker.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.platforms    = { :ios => "9.0" }
  s.source_files = "LoudSpeakerModule.{h,m}"
end
```

Note that the values for name, homepage, author, source, and source_files may vary depending on the package you are using. You can find the correct values in the package's documentation.

After creating the podspec file, run the following command in your project's root directory:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

And I prefer you try to find another package

Comment: i have tried this method but its not fixed this package is not working

Comment: I've updated the answer hope it helps you

Comment: this also not working sir @ Louay Sleman

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: no sir im trying but i got new error